# Normalising volume on sound files

Tags: sound, mp3, conversion

I have a bunch of mp3s that are awfully quiet. Even on max volume on my player, they're hardly intelligible.

On the other hand, I have a few mp3's with perfect volume all over, could be used as a reference. A coworker mentioned there is a way to "normalise" volume on sound files, but couldn't help me on how exactly it's done.

Anyone know how to do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EASYMP3GAIN will work. Look in the ubuntu software center. It's pretty simple , when you run it you can select the whole directory and normalize the all the songs

MP3DIAGS will do it too, however it's interface is much more difficult to understand.